# Failed to create thumbnail, removing original error without a rule

Tags: android, bitmap, mediastore

I use my own application to take picture, there is no errors there, I get the picture as a bitmap and show it on an ImageView successfully.

I have 500*500 pixel images, and when I click a place, the Bitmap is sent over to be filtered, and after that the error is gone. And when I go to original filter, I can save the original image too.

Think of it like Retrica, you take the photo, go to another activity, but you can't save the original image without going to filter2 and clicking back the original filter.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(PictureTaken.this.getContentResolver(), myBitmap, ""+System.currentTimeMillis(), "App1");
```

Failed to create thumbnail, removing original

It gives me this error, I think because it cannot generate a thumbnail, it removes the image too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late may be useful to someone. I got the same error.. I forgot to set bitmap to the myBitmap. check you are passing bitmap properly.